# React Native - .xcworkspace doesn't contain any files after pulling from git

Tags: ios, react-native

I've just pulled my latest commits at home, run `npm install` and then get some issues running `react-native run-ios`:

*xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "Contractor" does not contain a scheme named "Contractor". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.*

When I opened up the `.xcworkspace` in XCode there's nothing in the project navigator sidebar and no schemes. If I open up the `.xcodeproj` file, all of my source files are there, so it seems like there's been some disconnect between the workspace and the project?

I'm not really sure where to go from here..

Answer (score 2):

Are you using cocoapods? I ran into the same issue, `cd PROJECT_ROOT/ios && pod install` fix it for me.

Comment: Indeed the install command worked. A pod update just didn't do it for me, though it did show the project file there was still no scheme.